# Android: How to keep layout stable when replacing fragments?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

currently I'm developing a board game for Android, which mainly consists of the folling UI elements

- a board (surprise!)
- controls
- a TextView to display hints and a button to dismiss the displayed hint

To give the board as much screen real estate as possible and to keep the layout flexible, I implemented a fragment for the controls and another fragment for displaying hints.

At the moment I'm using the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/default_padding">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_and_hints_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <some.package.BoardView
        android:id="@+id/board"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/input_and_hints_container" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When the activity starts, it places the controls-fragment into the FrameLayout. The controls contain a button to display hints (if applicable), which replaces the controls-fragment with the show-hints-fragment. The show-hints-fragment has a dismiss button, which replaces the show-hints-fragment with the controls-fragment.

My problem is, that the show-hints-fragment may take more (or less) space than the controls-fragment, which results in a resize of the board. (I'd prefer to keep the board size stable, as long as there is no orientation change.)

I've thought of two possible approaches to keep the layout stable:

1. Keep the initial size of the controls-fragment as state, implement a custom view for the show-hints-fragment and have it return the same dimensions in it's onMeasure. My gut feeling is, that this is overcomplicated and rather ugly. I'd assume that there has to be a more elegant solution.
2. Use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) to contain the two fragments. I've never used a ViewPager before, so I'm just speculating that this would keep the layout stable.

There's bound to be more options, so I'd like to know what the best approach is.

Thanks & all the best.

Comment: Just specify a fixed height or weight for the container layout?

Comment: Hi corsair, thank you very much for you input, but I don't think that approach would be very flexible. The controls get measured and layed out nicely without a fixed height; my only requirement is that the replacement fragment should not take up more vertical space than that. Maybe a custom ViewGroup implementation is the way to go. I'll keep researching.

Comment: OK, then move the replacement fragment inside the first one on top of it's own layout matching the layout height (should be doable if you have a `FrameLayout` at it's layout root).

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research I decided to implement my own custom ViewGroup. Judging by the little amount of state and code that needed to be written, this seems to be a workable solution.

I used [this article](http://arpitonline.com/2012/07/01/creating-custom-layouts-for-android/) as a starting point.

My solution cuts a lot of corners (based on domain knowledge) - it lays out it's children from bottom to top. The last child simply takes the remaining spaces. 
A specific child get's a different (exact) measure spec, to keep things stable:

```
public class PlayViewGroup extends ViewGroup {
    private int mMeasuredControlHeight = -1;

    public PlayViewGroup(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PlayViewGroup(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(final boolean changed, final int l, final int t, final int r, final int b) {
        final int width = r - l;
        final int height = b - t;
        int currentChildBottom = height;
        for(int i=0; i <this.getChildCount(); i++){
            final View view = getChildAt(i);
            final int childLeft = (width - view.getMeasuredWidth()) / 2;
            final int childRight = width - childLeft;
            final int childTop = currentChildBottom - view.getMeasuredHeight();
            view.layout(childLeft, childTop, childRight, currentChildBottom);
            currentChildBottom -= view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int wspec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        int remainingHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        for (int i=0; i<getChildCount(); i++) {
            boolean controlPanelFound = false;
            final View view = getChildAt(i);
            int hspec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(remainingHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            if (view.getId() == R.id.input_and_hints_container) {
                final FrameLayout mContainer = (FrameLayout) view;
                if (mContainer.getChildCount() == 1) {
                    final View containedView = mContainer.getChildAt(0);
                    if (containedView instanceof InputPanel) {
                        controlPanelFound = true;
                    } else if (containedView != null && mMeasuredControlHeight > 0) {
                        hspec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mMeasuredControlHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                        wspec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                    }
                }
            }

            view.measure(wspec, hspec);
            if (controlPanelFound) {
                mMeasuredControlHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
            remainingHeight -= view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This probably could be achieved with `RelativeLayout` too, with explicit layout alignments.